# Reading a SQL Server table into Orbeon

Tags: orbeon

I am using the latest version of Orbeon 19 with SQL Server 2019.  I would like to read a bunch of records (like a table) for a specific period and entity into an Orbeon form.  The use case is : the transactions for a period of time for a user (or the current user).  I am not a strong coder so I am struggling to connect to SQL and retrieve fields and get these formatted into the Orbeon Builder.  I am also using Tomcat 8.

It would be awesome if I could then add a comment and write back to the database, but that might be a bit much.  Let me know if more detail is required.

Any guidance is great as the documentation doesn't contain any help for the use case or when using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is possible, but often not the best approach, as it creates 2 copies of your data: one in "your database" and one in the "Orbeon Forms database" (even if both are on SQL Server). This then creates the need for synchronizing data back and forth, which often isn't a simple thing to do.

Instead, I'd recommend you try to keep each piece of information in one database. Maybe most of the data will stay in your database, but additional information captured by the forms will go in the Orbeon Forms database. Or maybe the Orbeon Forms database won't be used at all, and when people save the form, you will have your own code that saves the data in your database.